# Check if Replication Enabled

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replication

What's the easiest way to check if replication is enabled in a SQL 2000, 2005, and 2008 compatible format? Don't need any status info...just to know if it's enabled for a DB. I need this because I want my Db Migration code to throw an exception if replication is enabled before it tries to perform schema updates.

Thanks.

Comment: There are various heuristic methods, but no simply status query. In addition, replication can be quite granular, so it may be enabled on some objects within the database which you're not going to modify anyway.

Comment: To check if replication is installed: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/246910/how-we-can-we-know-sql-replication-components-installed-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at this article, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179855.aspx) says "When a user database is configured as a Publisher or a Subscriber, replication adds system tables to the database. These tables are removed when a user database is removed from a replication topology"

You could look for the existence of one of these tables listed in the article as proof of replication, and proceed with your query accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

I found this query, but this only works in SQL 2005 and higher versions (Not for SQL 2000 verson).

**T-SQL Query**

```
  select name, is_published, is_subscribed, is_merge_published, is_distributor
  from sys.databases
  where is_published = 1 or is_subscribed = 1 or
  is_merge_published = 1 or is_distributor = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS IsPublished
FROM  sys.databases
WHERE (is_published | is_subscribed | is_merge_published) AND (name = @dbname)
```

This will get you a list of the dbs that are published.  you can optionally included distribution dbs by adding the is_distributor

```
SELECT name
FROM  sys.databases
WHERE (is_published | is_subscribed | is_merge_published | is_distributor = 1)
```

To my anything worth doing is worth doing again so I create a user defined function (you could use a stored procedure just as easily):

```
-- ================================================
-- Author:      J. Duke Rogers
--              Communicore Technologies &
--              Triangle Forensics
-- Create date: 07.25.20
-- Description: If @dbname is null or '' it uses 
--              the database in which it is defined
-- WARNING:     May cause black hole(s)
-- ================================================
CREATE FUNCTION fn_IsReplicationEnabled 
(
    @dbname sysname =NULL
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result int

    IF (@dbname is null or @dbname='')
        set @dbname=DB_NAME()

    SELECT @Result=COUNT(*)
        FROM  
            sys.databases
        WHERE 
            is_published | is_subscribed | is_merge_published=1 AND [name] = @dbname
    
    IF @Result is null or @Result <0 or @Result>1
        return CAST('Something impossible has occurred, singularity and/or black hole
                     imminent, don helmet!' as bit)
    
    RETURN IIF(@Result=1,1,0)

END
GO
```

IMHO

Answer (score 0):

From: [www.mssqlinsider.com/2013/09/check-databases-part-replication](http://www.mssqlinsider.com/2013/09/check-databases-part-replication/):

```
SELECT 
    name as [Database name],
    CASE is_published 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
        ELSE 'Yes' 
        END AS [Is Published],
    CASE is_merge_published 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
        ELSE 'Yes' 
        END AS [Is Merge Published],
    CASE is_distributor 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
        ELSE 'Yes' 
        END AS [Is Distributor],
    CASE is_subscribed 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
        ELSE 'Yes' 
        END AS [Is Subscribed]
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4
```

Comment: This statement has no FROM clause.

Comment: Not sure if this counts as plagiarism or not.  [Source](http://www.mssqlinsider.com/2013/09/check-databases-part-replication/) (in case of edits)

Comment: [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) states that the 'is_subscribed' column will always return 0.